# Is there a name for a number whose factors' exponents are all prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, terminology, factoring

For instance, $864$, whose factorization is $2^5\cdot3^3$.

Comment: If so, it's probably not standard; [A056166](http://oeis.org/A056166) is the only matching sequence.